# In-app-billing Play Store cache

Tags: android, caching, in-app-billing

I am using in-app-billing v3 to allow users to purchase the premium version of my app with unlocked options. The app will check for the purchase when it starts with queryInventory. As I understand it, the response can be cached within the Play Store app data so that if there is no internet connection, it can still come back as true. However, this cache doesn't seem to last that long. I.E. if you're somewhere without internet for a few hours and bring up my app, it can't verify the purchase and reverts to the non-premium version until it is started again with an internet connection.

Is everyone seeing this?